# disable selection of past months and enable selection on future month and date in materialdatetimepicker in android

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Integrating https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker this library in android app,here is my code to select date and time.I'm able to implement enabling future date with in month and disable past date with in month but i want to implement disable option for past months and enable selection option for future months.here is my code

```
private void selectDate() {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog12h = TimePickerDialog
            .newInstance(new OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view,
                        int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    Object c = pad3(hourOfDay);
                    selectedTime = new StringBuilder()
                            .append(pad2(hourOfDay)).append(":")
                            .append(pad(minute)).append(c);

                    String str_date = selectedDate.toString() + " "
                            + selectedTime + "";
                    String str_date_current = currentDate.toString() + " "
                            + mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                            + mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa");
                    DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
                    DateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                    try {
                        String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(formatter
                                .parse(str_date));
                        // Date date=formatter.parse(str_date);
                        String reformattedStr2 = myFormat.format(formatter2
                                .parse(str_date_current));

                        date = (Date) myFormat.parse(reformattedStr);
                        Date date2 = (Date) myFormat.parse(reformattedStr2);

                        if (date2.before(date)) {
                            bookAppointment();
                        } else {

                            selectDate();
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    ChatThread.this,
                                    "We all wish we could go back in the past ;)",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Today is " + date.getTime());

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

    datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            new OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog,
                        int year, int month, int day) {

                    selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(pad(day))
                            .append("-")
                            .append(mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                            .append("-")
                            .append(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

                    currentDate = new StringBuilder()
                            .append(mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                            .append("-").append(pad(month + 1)).append("-")
                            .append(pad(year));
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    try {
                        Date date1 = format.parse(selectedDate.toString());
                        Date date2 = format.parse(currentDate.toString());
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(date2);
                        datePickerDialog.setMinDate(cal);

                        if (date2.equals(date1) || date2.compareTo(date1)<0) {
                            timePickerDialog12h.show(getFragmentManager(),
                                    "");

                        } else {
                            selectDate();
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    ChatThread.this,
                                    "We all wish we could go back in the past ;)",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    // datePickerDialog.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in materialdatetimepicker you should just set the minimum date

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            dpd.setMinDate(cal);
```

So the DatePickerDialog will be like below code

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                            AddTask.this,
                            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    );

                dpd.setThemeDark(true);
                dpd.vibrate(true);
                dpd.dismissOnPause(true);
                dpd.showYearPickerFirst(false);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            dpd.setMinDate(cal);
                dpd.setAccentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_orange));
                dpd.setTitle("Date Picker");
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method and you'll get what exactly you are looking for

```
 public void dateSet() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            selectedtime = selectedtime + year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;
            selectedtimetosend = selectedtime;
            selecteddate = year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;

        }
    }, now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dpd.setMinDate(now);
    try {
        final Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
        dpd.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Copy and Paste and see the result**
**I use this in Fragment. change it if you want it in activity. 
Feel free to ask**